# Добавить или удалить элемент во вложенном массиве в зависимости от наличия?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Структура документа

```
[{
  answers:[{
    // поля...
    comments:[{
      //поля...
      likes:['сюда id в виде строки']
    }]
  }]
}]
```

Вопрос в следующем, нужно проверить существует ли id в многоуровневом вложенном подмасссиве likes (*answers*=>*comments*=>**likes**), если не существует, то добавить id, если существует то удалить. Добавляю так

```
.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        _id: id,
      },
      {
        $push: {
          "answers.$[].comments.$[comments].likes": likes.liked,
        },
      },
      {
        arrayFilters: [
          {
            "comments._id": likes.comment_id,
          },
        ],
        new: true,
      },
    );
```

Comment: Замени картинки текстами...

Comment: Все поменял на код)

Comment: Ты такое хочешь провернуть одной командой?

Comment: Сам поиск по твоему условию будет выглядеть так `{"answers.comments.likes": <твое_ИД>}`...

Comment: Не обязательно одной, разные вариант рассматриваю, пока накопал только $cond, $switch(но не уверен) и находил что то с callback функцией.

Comment: Искать и удалять можно так - `.updateOne({"answers.comments.likes": 5}, {$pull: {"answers.$[].comments.$[].likes": 5}})`. Пятерка это такой ИД в моей тестовой БД

Comment: Если использовать поисковый запрос и CB-функцию - можно использовать следующий подход. Если документ найден - удаляй ИД. Если документ не найден - добавляй ИД.

Comment: updateOne возвращает объект где написано были ли изменения?(если мне память не изменяет)

Comment: Все верно. Но пока речь шла про сами "действия", а не возвращаемые значения. :) Если нужно еще и возвращать сами данные - так это `findAndModify` с ключами...

Comment: получается приходят данные { id комментария,id того кто лайкнул }. Я делаю updateOne, если там ничего не происходит то добавляю как во втором коде к вопросу

Comment: Как по мне, так структура у тебя не совсем удобная для работы... От того и ты начинаешь страдать. Ответы и комментарии - все в одной куче. Я бы такое разделил по разным коллекциям...

Comment: Я вчера думал по этому поводу) у меня сложная структура документа, много запросов к бд будет получатся если все делить. У меня документ по аналогии как тут, есть вопрос=> комментарии к вопросу, ответы=> комментарии к ответам + лайки итд. 
По моему вопросу все получилось. Написал ```findOneAndUpdate({"answers.comments.likes": 5}, {$pull: {"answers.$[].comments.$[].likes": 5}})``` если возвращает null то findOneAndUpdate как в вопросе(добавляю id)

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/ - сделайте пример, с которым можно поиграться. Тогда наверняка получите ответ.

Comment: Спасибо) вроде нашел решение) Видел этот сайт, жалко там мало методов для работы)

Comment: Примечание: символ скобки не является знаком препинания. Ставьте в конце предложений точку, восклицательный или вопросительный знак. Или у вас на клавиатуре клавиша не работает?

Comment: Все работает. Буду иметь ввиду. Спасибо.